# Ensure a page has downloaded correctly in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am writing a basic screen scraping script using Mechanize and BeautifulSoup (BS) in Python. However, the problem I am running into is that for some reason the requested page does not download correctly every time. I am concluding this because when searching the downloaded pages using BS for present tags, I get an error. If I download the page again, it works.

Hence, I would like to write a small function that checks to see if the page has correctly downloaded and re-download if necessary (I could also solve it by figuring out what goes wrong, but that is probably too advanced for me). My question is how would I go about checking to see if the page has been downloaded correctly?

Comment: Show us the offending code part. Else any suggestion would be to general to be useful to you.

Comment: "solve it by figuring out what goes wrong".  Good idea.  Dump the output from mechanize to see what went wrong.  Perhaps that's a better question to ask.

Comment: I used Denis's suggestion to create a small function which checks every page that is downloaded, however that did not work so I dump the output as per S.Lott's suggestion and lo and behold, its a problem with BeautifulSoup... for some reason BS is randomly not finding the tags, even though they are in the document. Recreating the BS object doesn't work either, I have to re-download and then recreate and it works. I'll do some more testing and come back with another question. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check for a tag you expect to be there, and if it fails, repeat the download.

```
page = BeautifulSoup(page)

while page.body = None:
    #redownload the page
    page = BeautifulSoup(page)
#now you can use the data
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may simple search for html ending tag  if this tag is in - this is a valid page.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic solution is to check that the `</html>` closing tag exists. That will allow you to detect truncation of the page.

Anything else, and you will have to describe your failure mode more clearly.